# Patch Android security provider in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I am building an Android app in Flutter and Fortify code scan reported the warning: The application does not use the Google Play Service Updated Security Provider which may leave it vulnerable to future vulnerabilities in OpenSSL Library.

For a native Android app, I could follow the guide [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider) but how do I fix the warning in a Flutter app?

Comment: Any update in this? did you find any solution?

Comment: Yes, see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your MainActivity, use the code from this snippet by Google

```
private const val ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE = 1

    /**
     * Sample activity using {@link ProviderInstaller}.
     */
    class MainActivity : Activity(), ProviderInstaller.ProviderInstallListener {
    
        private var retryProviderInstall: Boolean = false
    
        //Update the security provider when the activity is created.
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, this)
        }
    
        /**
         * This method is only called if the provider is successfully updated
         * (or is already up-to-date).
         */
        override fun onProviderInstalled() {
            // Provider is up-to-date, app can make secure network calls.
        }
    
        /**
         * This method is called if updating fails; the error code indicates
         * whether the error is recoverable.
         */
        override fun onProviderInstallFailed(errorCode: Int, recoveryIntent: Intent) {
            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().apply {
                if (isUserResolvableError(errorCode)) {
                    // Recoverable error. Show a dialog prompting the user to
                    // install/update/enable Google Play services.
                    showErrorDialogFragment(this@MainActivity, errorCode, ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE) {
                        // The user chose not to take the recovery action
                        onProviderInstallerNotAvailable()
                    }
                } else {
                    onProviderInstallerNotAvailable()
                }
            }
        }
    
        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int,
                                      data: Intent) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            if (requestCode == ERROR_DIALOG_REQUEST_CODE) {
                // Adding a fragment via GoogleApiAvailability.showErrorDialogFragment
                // before the instance state is restored throws an error. So instead,
                // set a flag here, which will cause the fragment to delay until
                // onPostResume.
                retryProviderInstall = true
            }
        }
    
        /**
         * On resume, check to see if we flagged that we need to reinstall the
         * provider.
         */
        override fun onPostResume() {
            super.onPostResume()
            if (retryProviderInstall) {
                // We can now safely retry installation.
                ProviderInstaller.installIfNeededAsync(this, this)
            }
            retryProviderInstall = false
        }
    
        private fun onProviderInstallerNotAvailable() {
            // This is reached if the provider cannot be updated for some reason.
            // App should consider all HTTP communication to be vulnerable, and take
            // appropriate action.
        }
    }
```

[Link to android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider)

Comment: classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'  (build.gradle Project)
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:18.0.1"  (build.gradle App)

(MainActivity imports ->)

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle
    import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
    import com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller;
    import com.google.android.gms.security.ProviderInstaller.ProviderInstallListener;